# Qual é a origem da palavra "religião"?

Tags: significado, etimologia, origem-histórica, origem

Quero saber, qual é a origem da palavra *religião*.

O que significa?

Ela é uma palavra traduzida para o português?

Qual seu o idioma originário?

Quando começou a ser utilizada?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Religião*** é no seu moderno sentido primário um conjunto de crenças num ser ou força (ou seres ou forças) superior e sobrenatural, criador e sustentador de tudo quanto existe, e um conjunto de atitudes, práticas e regras associados a essas crenças. Isto é uma definição muito geral nas minhas palavras. A [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religi%C3%A3o) tem um artigo desenvolvido sobre os assunto, e o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/religi%C3%A3o) e o [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=&t=&palavra=religi%C3%A3o) trazem mais uma porção de aceções, para além do sentido primário.

A palavra vem do latim *religio* e já aparece em textos galaico-portugueses do século XIII, com as grafias *religião* e *religion*; também se encontra neste século *religioso*, do latim *religiosus* (dicionário Houaiss, Lisboa, 2003). Não se encontrar a palavra anteriormente não significa que ela não estivesse já em uso: chegou até nós pouquíssimo material em português dos séculos anteriores. Dada a importância da religião nos tempos antigos, e como a palavra vem já do latim, quase de certeza que esteve presente na língua o tempo todo na evolução do latim até ao português.

Segundo o Houaiss, o latim *religio* significava ‘culto religioso, práticas religiosas’. As palavras francesa e inglesa *religion* vem também do latim *religio*, a inglesa, via francês. E o [Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=religion), dicionário etimológico da língua inglesa, explica mais pormenorizadamente o significado e possíveis origens do latim *religio* (tradução minha):

> “respeito para com o que é sagrado, reverência para com os deuses; consciência, sentido de correção, obrigação moral, temor aos deuses; serviço divino, observância religiosa; qualquer religião, fé, modo de adoração ou culto; santidade”, e no latim tardio, “vida monástica” (século V).
>
> De acordo com Cícero [*religio*] deriva de *relegere* “passar novamente por” (numa leitura ou pensamento), de *re-* “novamente” […] + *legere* “ler” […]. Contudo, a etimologia popular entre os antigos (Servius, Lactanius, Agostinho) e a interpretação de muitos autores modernos relacionam [*religio*] com *religare* “ligar, atar firmemente” […], por via da noção de “impor uma obrigação a”, ou “ligação, vínculo entre humanos e deuses”. Neste caso, o *re-* seria um intensificador. Outra origem possível é *religiens* “cuidadoso”, contrário de *negligens*.

Procurando no  [Corpo Informatizado do Português Medieval](http://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/) encontram-se a partir do século XIII vários exemplos de *religion, religiõ, religiom, religiam* e *religiões*, todos aparentemente com o sentido de ‘vida monástica’, isto é, a vida de monges, freiras, etc. em comunidades religiosas. Hoje, neste sentido, diríamos normalmente, não *religião*, mas *ordem, congregação religiosa*; mas o [Michaelis 7](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=&t=&palavra=religi%C3%A3o) ainda regista esta aceção de *religião*. Só a partir do século XV é que encontrei *religião* (nas suas diversas variantes gráficas) com o moderno sentido de ‘conjunto de crenças e atitudes relacionadas com o divino’. Exemplos com a minha “tradução”, espero que correta, para português atual:

> Ena Gran Bretanna foi hũa sazon / que un mõesteiro de **religion** / grand' ouv' y de monges, que de coraçon / servian a Virgen bẽeita sen par.
>   <sub>Na Grã Bretanha foi uma época, que houve um grande mosteiro de **religião** e monges, que de coração serviam a Virgem bendita sem par</sub>
>   [*Cantigas de Santa Maria*, 1264-84 (aqui edição de 1959)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=I11fAAAAMAAJ&q=%22que%20un%20m%C3%B5esteiro%20de%20religion%22&dq=%22que%20un%20m%C3%B5esteiro%20de%20religion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQzazGztLVAhXJuxQKHXvFDmQQ6AEIKjAB)
>
> Est’ ome[…] soube senpre ben sen mal / e Santa Maria, a que pod' e val, / amou mais que al ren, e por lle leal / seer entrou logo en **religion**.
>   <sub>Este homem […] soube sempre bem sem mal e amou mais que [qualquer] outra coisa Santa Maria, a que pode e vale, e por lhe ser leal entrou logo em **religião**</sub>
>   [*Cantigas de Santa Maria*, 1264-84 (Wikisource)](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Cantigas_de_Santa_Maria/CCLXV)
>
> Deffendem(os) firmemẽte q(ue) nenhuũ clerigo segral nẽ de **religiõ** nõ seya osado de tomar nenhuũ p(re)ço por dar fossas nen logar hu as façã.
>   <sub>Defendemos firmemente que nenhum clérigo secular ou de **religião** tenha ousadia de tomar preço por dar cova [para sepultura] ou lugar onde as façam</sub>
>   [Afonso X, Foro Real, Beira Alta, 1280? (em Elisângela Santos, *Elementos Textuais*](https://repositorio.ufba.br/ri/bitstream/ri/8388/3/Elis%C3%A2ngela%20Santana%20dos%20Santos%20-%20elementos%20textuais.pdf)

E exemplo mais antigo que encontrei com o sentido moderno é de [D. Duarte, *Leal Conselheiro*, 1437-8, (edição de 1842):](https://books.google.pt/books?id=A98_AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA283&lpg=PA283&dq=%22xp%C3%A3a%20relegiom%22&source=bl&ots=57KgQmUB9W&sig=c6q533SLBthYvsV4L5nc8JUHGzg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM8KSSndbVAhXDtRoKHaPsAPMQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22xp%C3%A3a%20relegiom%22&f=false)

> Estas tres virtudes suso [‘acima’] scriptas, scilicet [latim, ‘a saber’], fe, sperança, e caridade […] e das outras quatro, scilicet, prudencia, justiça, temperança e fortelleza, […] E no livro das Collaçõões de sam Joham Casiano, e seus stabellicymentos, os quaaes, ainda que trautem segundo a xpãa [‘cristã’] **religiom**, todo [‘tudo’] porem fillosofalmente he fundado sobre as virtudes e seus contrairos.

Answer (score 2):

A definição de Religião é muito contestada.

Certamente vem da palavra latim "re" + "ligare". O prefixo `re` indica uma intensidade da palavra que vem depois. A palavra "ligare" é onde não existe um consenso etimológico, pois vai da interpretação.

Pode ser interpretado como "Religar". No sentido de se reconectar com Deus.

Outra interpretação muito difundida por monastérios cristãos em 1200 traça `ligare` para o proto-indio Europeu "atar". Entao ficaria algo como "atar com mais intensidade", essa visão foi muito usada para a idéia de pregar votos monásticos, etc.

E a terceira interpretação, que parece ser o primeiro registro da palavra "religare" na história, é atribuída ao filósofo grego Cicero, onde o sentido era de viver o "[Mos maiorum](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mos_maiorum)", o código moral romano, guiado por virtudes fundamentais que favorecem a expansão da consciência, senso de Verdade, obrigação moral ou dever para com qualquer coisa, um dos princípios é `Religio`, relacionado com a união entre deuses e mortais.

Comment: Bem-vindo Lucas! Obrigado pela contribuição. Sugiro que você inclua alguma referência para dar mais base à sua descrição da etimologia da palavra (numa rápida busca encontrei https://www.etymonline.com/word/religio- , mas deve haver melhores).

Comment: Lucas, bem-vindo ao site! Eu não entendi algo: dizes que os monastérios em 1200 sabiam da existência do proto-indo-europeu?